# How to get IMEI Number in Cordova?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova-plugins

I am developing an application in **Cordova** which requires to get the **IMEI number** of any device programatically. Cordova Provides the **UUID** number but that won't work for me, I need IMEI number.

Or is there any plugin to get the IMEI Number directly?

"IMEI PhoneGap Plugin in Android"  it gives custom plugin that only work for the android I need plugin which support for both android as well as ios.

"How to programmatically get the devices IMEI/ESN in Android" it gives java code for the android so how do I convert java code in angularjs?

Is there any plugin available or not? It simple as that.

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300839/imei-phonegap-plugin-in-android

Comment: Yaah! I already  gone through that links but could not able to solve my problem. I need any Cordova Plugin to get IMEI Number or need that code in javascript or jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, OP asks for a solution which works not only in android but in ios too.

Comment: use this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43651210/1770868

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way to get IMEI in **android device only**

$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin.git

The above listed is cordova plugin to get device information. get method of that plugin
generate a JSON In which you can see your android device’s IMEI number.

**Using code:**

```
var deviceInfo = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/DeviceInformation");
deviceInfo.get(
   function(result) {
      console.log("result = " + result);
   },function() {
      console.log("error");
});
```

**Without using code:**

- In device’s hardware where you insert your SIM
- In device’s Setting->About phone->Status->IMEI OR (SIM status ->
  IMEI)
- Dial: *#06#

IMEI number is actually SIM card port number.  so you  can not access IMEI number of SIM-LESS devices. (ex.:- without SIM tablet)

Comment: May I know for which device are you using for this?

Answer (score 1):

You've been linked to how to do it in Android. It is [not possible in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902222/how-to-get-device-imei-number-programmatically-using-xcode-to-phonegap) - Apple does not permitt it. UUID will have to do.

Comment: I have very basic knowledge of cordova. the above listed links give me the uuid which will not work for my app. I need IMEI number, and that link does not provide me the IMEI number of my device.

Comment: @PooravC_x_J Again, **this is not possible in iOS**.

Comment: yaah! I got that It will not work in iOS. and Android provides uuid which also not works for my app. thanks

Comment: @PooravC_x_J The questions you got linked to show how to get IMEI on Android. Please, read before commenting.

Comment: So is there a way to obtain an unique identifier for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Another cordova plugin not mentioned here is `cordova-plugin-imei`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-imei

Example:

```
window.plugins.imei.get(
  function(imei) {
    console.log("got imei: " + imei);
  },
  function() {
    console.log("error loading imei");
  }
);
```